# API call to execute a python function

Tags: python, graphql, fastapi

I'm building an API for a small desktop application. Frontend Electron (React), and FastAPI (Python) Backend.
I want a functionally of pushing on a button at the Frontend GUI, which will call a python function and refresh the window with the fresh reatrived data or response.
What will be the best way for achieving that? I'm guessing it will involve a lot of async coding.
Currently, I think of GraphQL API implantation, because I've worked with it in the past, but if this mechanism is easier to implant in REST, so be it.

Comment: What difficulty are you having using the JS `fetch()` function?

Comment: Simple FastAPI/React tutorial: https://testdriven.io/blog/fastapi-react/

Comment: A single `fetch()` call to an API endpoint returning JSON should do it straight out the box? No need to complicate it in any way with "lot of async coding" or GraphQL?

Answer (score 2):

So for such applications I like to use a library called **Axios** but you can also use the built in javascript `fetch()` function as well.  I'll show you a snippet of me using the `useEffect()` hook with `fetch()` to make a get request:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const myNewFunction = async() => {
     await fetch(my_get_url.com)
        .then(res => res.json)
        .then((data) => {
           console.log(data) //This is your JSON
        });
  }
  myNewFunction();
}, []);
```

That template above will work for anything really. Inside that promise with the JSON, you can update state and so on. The only way to run an async function in a hook, is by creating the function inside a variable and then calling it. `fetch()` is a native Javascript function and there are no libraries for you to import. Though if you wanted to look at the more popular ways of doing you can look at **Axios** but for your purposes, this should work out fine.